# Understanding Feynman's quote on how to find the 'true path' for which action is least.

Tags: calculus

In the lecture [*Principle of Least Action*](http://www.feynmanlectures.caltech.edu/II_19.html) by Feynman, he introduced before us the *Calculus of Variations* in order to find out the '*true path*' for which the [action](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Action_(physics)) is least.

But then I stumbled across this:

> When we have a quantity which has a minimum—for instance, in an ordinary function like the temperature—one of the properties of the minimum is that **if we go away from the minimum in the *first* order, the deviation of the function from its minimum value is only *second* order. At any place else on the curve, if we move a small distance the value of the function changes also in the first order.** But at a minimum, a tiny motion away makes, in the first approximation, no difference.

I'm having problem in conceiving what Feynman wanted to tell by the blocked sentence in the above passage.

What did he mean by *first* order and *second* order? Why does a '*tiny* motion'other than the minimum, change the function by *first* order?

Can any one tell me what this passage is actually talking about?

Comment: When you expand a smooth function f(x) at one of its minimum, say $x_0$, one has $f(x) \approx  f(x_0) + \frac12 f''(x_0) (x-x_0)^2$. When one expand it near other point $x_1$, one has $f(x) \approx f(x_1) + f'(x_1) (x-x_1) + \frac12 f''(x_1)(x-x_1)^2$. The first order/second order refer to when you expand something, whether the leading correction is linear or quadratic in response of the change of underlying variable.

Comment: @achillehui: Thanks! Please turn this to answer! How could I not get he was talking about expansion... damn.

Comment: I know this is late, but first order, and on refers to the first derivative, etc. It seems that if you change the first derivative you would be changing the second to achieve that result. The function is basically zeroth order, so a change in f would require a change in the first.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As achille hui wrote in the comments, Feynman is referring to the Taylor expansion of a well-behaved function $f(x)$. If $f(x)$ has a minimum at, say $x=a$, then $f'(a)=0$. Thus the series expansion becomes

$$f(x) = f(a) + \frac12f''(a) (x-a)^2 + \frac1{3!}f^{(3)}(a)(x-a)^3+\cdots$$

Note there is no $(x-a)$ term, which is referred to as the *first order* term. Order here refers to the power of each monomial. Now if we evaluate the function *at* $x=a$, then we simply find

$$f(a) = f(a).$$

However, evaluate the function at some *slightly* deviated value, like $x=a+\Delta$ and we find that the change in the function is

$$f(a+\Delta) = f(a) + \frac12f''(a) \Delta^2 + \frac1{3!}f^{(3)}(a)\Delta ^3+\cdots$$

If $\Delta$ is a rather small deviation, then the majority of the change has come from the second order term.

$$f(a+\Delta) \approx f(a) + \frac12f''(a) \Delta^2 $$